# group dictionaries to by value

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
data1 = [
{key1: 1, key2: 1, count:  3},
{key1: 2, key2: 1, count: 15},
{key1: 3, key2: 1, count: 12},
{key1: 1, key2: 2, count: 13},
{key1: 2, key2: 2, count:  8},
]

data2 = [
key1:{1: 'value1_1', 2: 'value1_2', 3: 'value1_3'},
key2:{1: 'value2_1', 2: 'value2_2'},
]
```

I would like to combine those 2 dictionaries to 1 big dictionary that will look like that:

```
new_data = [
{key1: 1, key1_name: 'value1_1', key2: 1, key2_name: 'value2_1', count:  3},
{key1: 2, key1_name: 'value1_2', key2: 1, key2_name: 'value2_1', count: 15},
{key1: 3, key1_name: 'value1_3', key2: 1, key2_name: 'value2_1', count: 12},
{key1: 1, key1_name: 'value1_1', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', count: 13},
{key1: 2, key1_name: 'value1_2', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', count:  8},
{key1: 3, key1_name: 'value1_3', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', count:  0},
]
```

or maybe, like that:

```
new_data2 = [
{key1: {
value: 1, name: 'value1_1',
data: [
{value: 1, name: 'value2_1', count:   3},
{value: 2, name: 'value2_2', count:  13},
]},
{key1: {
value: 2, name: 'value1_2',
data: [
{value: 1, name: 'value2_1', count:  15},
{value: 2, name: 'value2_2', count:   8},
]},
{key3: {
value: 2, name: 'value1_3',
data: [
{value: 1, name: 'value2_1', count:  12},
{value: 2, name: 'value2_2', count:   0},
]}]
```

**Note1:** please see that each of the combined dict has an extra line with key1 = 3 and key 2 = 2, that this combination didn't had a value in the 'data2' dict and therefore the count value that was assign to this row is 0.

**Note2:** I'm not sure what is the "better" way to represent my data, like new_data1 or new_data2.

**Note3:** I would like to make it as generic as possible, I can't assume that the number of levels (in this case 2 levels, key1 and key2) will be fixed, so I need to allow for more level, meaning to be able to handle 3 or even 4 level.
For example (with 3 levels):

```
data = [
{key1: 1, key1_name: 'value1_1', key2: 1, key2_name: 'value2_1', key3: 1, key3_name: 'value3_1', count:  3},
{key1: 1, key1_name: 'value1_1', key2: 1, key2_name: 'value2_1', key3: 2, key3_name: 'value3_2', count:  2},
{key1: 1, key1_name: 'value1_1', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', key3: 1, key3_name: 'value3_1', count:  1},
{key1: 1, key1_name: 'value1_1', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', key3: 2, key3_name: 'value3_2', count:  6},
]
```

any help will be appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
key2_name = "key2_name"
key1_name = "key1_name"
key3_name = "key3_name"
data1 = [
    {key1: 1, key2: 1, count:  3},
    {key1: 2, key2: 1, count: 15},
    {key1: 3, key2: 1, count: 12},
    {key1: 1, key2: 2, count: 13},
    {key1: 2, key2: 2, count:  8}
]

data2 = { key1:{1: 'value1_1', 2: 'value1_2', 3: 'value1_3'}, key2:{1: 'value2_1', 2: 'value2_2'}
}

for dict_ in data1:
    dict_["key1_name"] = data2[key1][dict_[key1]]
    dict_["key2_name"] = data2[key2][dict_[key2]]

# equivalent to:
for dict_ in data1:
    for k, v in (key1_name, key1), (key2_name, key2):
        dict_[k] = data2[v][dict_[v]]
```

print(data1)

```
[{'count': 3, 'key2': 1, 'key1': 1, 'key2_name': 'value2_1', 'key1_name': 'value1_1'},
            {'count': 15, 'key2': 1, 'key1': 2, 'key2_name': 'value2_1', 'key1_name': 'value1_2'},
            {'count': 12, 'key2': 1, 'key1': 3, 'key2_name': 'value2_1', 'key1_name': 'value1_3'},
            {'count': 13, 'key2': 2, 'key1': 1, 'key2_name': 'value2_2', 'key1_name': 'value1_1'},
            {'count': 8, 'key2': 2, 'key1': 2, 'key2_name': 'value2_2', 'key1_name': 'value1_2'}]
```

[EDIT 3 keys example]

```
data1 = [
    {key1: 1, key2: 1, key3: 1, count:  3},
    {key1: 2, key2: 1, key3: 1, count: 15},
    {key1: 3, key2: 1, key3: 1, count: 12},
    {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 1, count: 13},
    {key1: 2, key2: 2, key3: 2, count:  8}
]
data2 = { key1:{1: 'value1_1', 2: 'value1_2', 3: 'value1_3'},
          key2:{1: 'value2_1', 2: 'value2_2'},
          key3:{1: 'value3_1', 2: 'value3_2'}
}
keys_name = [("%s_name"%v, v) for v in data2.keys()]
for dict_ in data1:
    for k, v in keys_name:
        dict_[k] = data2[v][dict_[v]]
```

Comment: but how do I add the "missing" row ({key1: 3, key1_name: 'value1_3', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', count:  0},), and also did you saw my Note3? because this code will not work if data1 and data had 3 keys

Comment: For missing row you want count=0 that's it ?

Comment: not sure what did you mean, the "messing" row should be: 
({key1: 3, key1_name: 'value1_3', key2: 2, key2_name: 'value2_2', count: 0},)
As I wrote in the previous comment

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to add rows those have no matching with data1 because it will imply to list all combinations between the keys. Also how do you will use the result ?

Comment: But this is exactly what I need, to have all the possible combinations, so that later on I could display it on a chart with bars with 0 for all the combinations that were not selected